# How to make an enum out of object keys?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to auto generate a key enum through typed keys in typescript?

e.g.

```
const myObj = { cat: true, literal: true };
const myKey: keyof typeof myObj = 'cat'
// Make as enum??
const myEnum = keyof typeof myObj as enum???

// Expected
// myEnum === myTypedEnum
// myEnum.cat === 'cat'
enum myTypedEnum {
    cat = 'cat',
    literal = 'literal'
}
```

Comment: To what end? Why not use the string literal type from `keyof typeof myObj`?

Comment: You can't programmatically generate `enum`s, but you can do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w62RYw) which might be good enough for your use cases. Does that work for you?  If not, please elaborate on what is missing.